# Why doesn't a form returned by a jquery AJAX call to PhP into a DIV not work?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to write an interactive web page and learn newer (10 years or less) web technologies along the way. So PhP, jquery and AJAX all fall into that category. I've pared down the code to just the essentials to ask this question.

I want my jquery to call a PhP program that will load two separate DIVs.  One is a data display area and the other is used to display the next form in the process chain. The trouble I'm having is that the form I'm returning isn't functional, even though it displays properly.

This is the main page (demo.php):

```
<?php 
echo <<<_END
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">     </script>
<script>
//
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btnDemo").click(function() {
     $("#PageForm").load("thetest.php", { paramYN: $("#paramYN").val() })
     $("#PageContent").load("nextpage.php");
  });
});

</script>
</head>
<title>The Title</title>
</head>
<body> 
<div id="PageHdr">
    <H4>Heading</h4>
</div>

<div id="PageForm">
    <form action="" id="Login"> 
        <br/>
    To show this form again enter   Y  otherwise enter   N    : <input type="text"    name="paramYN" id="paramYN" size=1>
    <input type="button" name="btnDemo" id="btnDemo" value="test it" /></form>
</div>

<div id="PageContent">
    <P>Put response here</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
_END;

?>
```

Here's the PhP program "thetest.php" which decides what to return into the PageForm DIV:

```
<?php //thetest.php
paramYN = $_POST["paramYN"];
if ($paramYN == "Y")
{
echo <<<_EOF
<form action="" id="Login"> 
<br/>This is the redisplay. Look for the date to change if it works after you click the      test it  button
<br/>To show this form again enter   Y  otherwise enter   N    : <input type="text" name="ParamYN" id="paramYN" size=1>
<input type="button" name="btnDemo" id="btnDemo" value="test it" /></form>
_EOF;
    $thetime = time();
    echo $thetime;
    exit();
}   
else
{
    echo "<html><head><title>PDO login</title></head><body>";
    echo "<h1>Congrats!</h1>";
    echo "</body></html>";
    exit();
}
?>
```

I only included the nextpage.php program because the full version of my program needs to update both DIV's. For the purpose of this demo it's as simple as this:

```
<?php //.php
echo "<h1>This is the new text for this place</h1>";
?>
```

So what is my problem here? Is it something in the way that I'm loading the DIV? Or is this something that is not doable?

Comment: Can you try changing $("#btnDemo").click(function() { to $('#login').on('click', '#btnDemo', function () { as you are loading content dynamically so its better to use event delegation

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I am new to jquery. Your change does not fix my problem but I will implement on your advice of it being a better practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your page first loads you use jQuery and "bind" a click event to your button "btnDemo".

The user then clicks the button "btnDemo" and triggers the load events. However, by doing this you are overriding your previously loaded button with the established jQuery events with a NEW button "btnDemo". This NEW button does NOT have the same bound click events.

You will need to re-apply the click events to the newly loaded button after it loads by adding the jQuery to the loading page "thetest.php".

```
echo <<<_EOF
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  //this will bind the click event to the newly loaded button
  $("#btnDemo").click(function() {
    $("#PageForm").load("thetest.php", { paramYN: $("#paramYN").val() })
    $("#PageContent").load("nextpage.php");
  });
});
</script>
<form> (the rest of your form here...)
_EOF;
```

Comment: This makes so much sense but I didn't know how to do that. Thanks. It worked in my demo and I'm going to try it in my full program. So, just to make sure I understand what this is doing, please verify or correct me if I'm wrong. The new code you added binds a function to the new button? Is that the work of the function() you added on the third line of your code?

Comment: Sorry, I just changed it. Please add the binding javascript to your page you are loading in. (thetest.php) See my edit above.

Comment: To answer your comment, the jQuery "load" method accepts three parameters. jquery.load('Param 1: the url', 'Param 2: the data', 'Param 3: the onComplete function'); I added a function for the third parameter that rebound the button. However, in your case this method will not work as you would endlessly need to re-bind after the button is loaded. For you, you will need to use what I posted above and simply put the binding ".click" script on the page you are loading in.

Comment: OK. I redid things per your changes. They work and actually make more sense to me.  At least I'm more comfortable with this code. I think the moral of the story is that the button is a new instance of that object and needs it's own code.

Comment: I also managed to get it working now in my main program. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
<?php //thetest.php
paramYN = $_POST["paramYN"];
if ($paramYN == "Y")
{
```

Try:

```
<?php //thetest.php
$paramYN = $_POST["paramYN"];
if ($paramYN == "Y")
{
```

Comment: Thanks. That was a sloppy bug on my part.